# gdal or numpy masking issue

Tags: qgis, gdal, numpy

Pretty baffled on this one.  I am trying to mask values from arrays.  They are nan values saved in geotiff from qgis as -3.40282e+38.  Numpy array 32 bit floating point vals loaded via

```
ds = gdal.Open(file/to/geotiff) 
arr = ds.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize)
```

I read in two arrays this way: `arr1` and `arr2`.  Then I create and mask and use it to remove nans:

```
mask = arr1!=np.nanmin(arr1)
temp = arr1[mask]
```

`temp` is used for calculations.  One array masked fine (out of two); *my nans are filtered out*.  But for some insidious reason the mask on `arr2` does not remove all the nan vals?  I've tried this for fun:

```
mask2 = arr2>-100
temp2 = arr2[mask2]
```

yet `temp2` still has `-3.40282e+38` present.  I am not in need of `copy.copy(var)`.  Any ideas outside of something dumb on my end?  Exacerbated but staying calm...

Comment: Maybe try using rasterio? https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `-100 > -3.40282e+38 = True` so mask2 will be all trues?

Comment: OK, I should probably remove this post.  It may make people dumber unless they are curious on basic masking syntax.  I was masking like this: `mask = arr1>100` and USING that mask on `arr2` because on a previous dataset with the same workflow the two datasets matched in their `nan` vals.  But apparently that was not the case and other qgis `nan float32` insanely negative numbers were hanging around undetected.  But I appreciate the help.  And I'm definitely using rasterio.  Seems `gdal` for command line and `rasterio` for `python`.  Thanks!